# Array count Should be Show in table view

Tags: iphone

i want show my NSMutableArray Count in a UILabel ,,,,,,,,,,

can any one help me

Comment: What have you tried so far? What about it didn't work? What would it mean to show an array in a label? How would it handle when the array has 200 elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray * anArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UILabel * aLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
aLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [anArray count]];
```